# How use LocationManager inside Timer?

Tags: android, timer

in my app I have a Background server and inside server class I have timer and inside timer I have a locationManager to find location :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,
                            locationListener);
```

but here I got this error :

```
java.lang.runtimeexception can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare();
```

my question here how to use locationManager inside timer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look Background service different with Activity  when you use runOnUiThread this is just possible with activity be careful OR if you use thread inside Service class you can do this like this :
inside service class write this :

```
static Activity ac;

    public static void setActivity(Activity a) {
        ac = a;

    }
```

and in your activity class  do this :

```
MyService.setActivity(this);
```

now this thread just like this :

```
(ac).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
 public void run() {});
```

I strongly recommend it to you do like what I did .

Comment: Please never do this.  See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298375/get-activitys-reference-from-a-service

The correct solution is much simpler.  Just create a Handler in the Service and use its post methods.

Answer (score 1):

The exception message may seem arcane if you don't know what Looper threads are, but it basically means exactly what it says: you can't create a Handler (or any object that contains a Handler) in a thread that is not a Looper.  Timer threads are not Loopers.  Many things in Android are intended to be created only on the UI thread, which is a Looper.

Trying to use a LocationListener "inside" a Timer doesn't make much sense, anyway.  The LocationListener's methods are called by the system, not by your code.   I suggest searching and reading up on *event-driven programming*.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Activity) getBaseContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,
                            locationListener); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: I got this error :
The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type MyService.

Comment: ((Activity) getBaseContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });